# Cannot count the cell amount

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, count, colormap

[image]

How can I count the colorwise cell amount of a layer file? The attribute table is hidden in the menu.

Is there any tool to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can create an Attribute Table using the [Build Raster Attribute Table](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/tools/data-management-toolbox/build-raster-attribute-table.htm) tool which:

> Create or update a table with information about the classes in your
> raster datasets. This is used primarily with discrete data.

The Attribute Table will show the count of pixels for each one of your classes (colors).

Comment: If you cannot build an attribute table then you have a raster of type float, you need to convert it to an integer using the int() tool.